# C++ Builder - File transfer

Tags: c++, c++builder, file-transfer

I am using Embarcadero C++ Builder and I am trying to collect as much information as I can so that I can start making my program. I want to make a client/server program. I am going to use databases and I need a way to transfer the database from the client computer to my server computer. And if a client PC gets destroyed for real I need to send the client his database back.

How can I do this?

Comment: How do you define client PC getting destroyed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you'll be using Firebird for your database, since it's the default for C++Builder/Delphi. Firebird maintains its database in a single file, so you will need to transfer it with network components, like [Indy](http://www.indyproject.org/), a great socket library that comes with C++Builder. [Here](http://delphi.about.com/od/networking/l/aa112602a.htm) is an article about data transfer through network with Delphi (easily translatable to C++). Good luck!